# Is it inefficient to Thread.Sleep(period) a BackgroundWorker on a mobile device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I've created a service that runs on a phone. The `OnCreate()` method is basically as follows:

```
public override void OnCreate()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
    {        
        while (true)
        {
            // do a web request & then destroy object

            Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0)); // 1 hour
        }          
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

As you can see, it does something and then sleeps for an hour.

While the thread is sleeping, is that using the device's power (excessively), or is it only when the thread is running? Is it inefficient to sleep the thread?

**Update**

This is what I did based on the suggestions:

```
        _displayTimer = new Timer();
        _displayTimer.Interval = 3600000;

        _displayTimer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { // do the stuff I need };
        _displayTimer.Start();
```

Comment: Why not use a Timer to run the thread every hour?

Comment: Maybe I should Jason! On that point, would that be more or less efficient, or indifferent?

Comment: @DaveDev It would be quite a bit more efficient as you're not wasting system resources creating a thread that is going to spend virtually all of it's time doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
 final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
 Timer timer = new Timer(false);
     TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             handler.post(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     // your processing here
                 }
             });
         } }; 
timer.schedule(timerTask, 60 *60 * 1000);
```

or for continuous ticks:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 60 *60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory, the task should not consume any resources while it's sleeping.  However, you prevent the runtime from doing any optimizations by writing it like that.

Using async, you can nicely write this as

```
    public void OnCreate()
    {
        Worker ();
    }

    async void Worker ()
    {
        while (true) {
            await Task.Delay (new TimeSpan (1, 0, 0)).ConfigureAwait (false);
            Console.WriteLine ("Do stuff!");
        }
    }
```

Or, if your work should happen on the UI thread, remove the `ConfigureAwait (false)`.